# How to setup dynamic dns without a dhcp and restricting every device to only set ther own dns and reverse dns record

Tags: dns, dynamic-dns, dyndns

I have already setup a BIND9 DNS Server in my intranet, but not want to setup dynamic dns capabilities to my server with the following requeriments:

1. No DHCP server required
2. Every device sets their own designated domain and nothing more.
3. Every device authenticates itself with some private key and the DNS server machine gets to get the public key of every device to authenticate the ip address update requests

How can configure my dns server to have such behavior?